# Layout for Property Page In Java

Tags: java, layout-manager

Is there a simple way to layout components in a panel in a similar fashion to a Property Page?  Where each property or setting has a label to the left and an editor component to the right of the panel.  Ideally, the labels should be left aligned, and the editors right aligned.  The editor left position should start from the largest label width plus a gap.  All editors should possibly have the same width.

At present, I can only do this using Netbeans designer using the "Free design" which corresponds to a Group layout in the generated code.  Even then I am using the designer to set location and size. And to be fair the generated code is god darn ugly.

**Generated Code**

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 198, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(199, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(275, 275, 275))
    );
```

Now bear in mind, I want to do this in code - not in Netbeans designer, and I also want to add many components.

I don't think Grid Layout with 2 columns and x rows will cut it as always splits into 2 columns in the middle of the panel.  Therefore where all labels are not too big, a huge gap will appear between itself and the editor.

Any tips, tricks, hacks are welcome.  I am thinking about writing my own layout manager to possibly do this.

Although it would be nice to write one and use it in the Netbeans designer.  But that is jumping the gun a little.

Answer (score 0):

The more requirements you want to set for the looks of your components, the more complicated the code you will need to write, in order to get there, will be.

If GridLayout does not behave the way you like, then GridBagLayout will. I am afraid though, that when you implement a GridBagLayout, your code will not look much nicer than what you've got here as an example.

I would stick with the existing layouts and ignore the "ugly" code generated by Netbeans designer. You do not have to mess with it anyway, since you do all the editing graphically.